# MetaMask Not showing Token Tab

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, metamask, exchanges, etherdelta

I have created my token "BBY" that is ERC20 complaint, right now I've sent all the tokens to the owner's address. I will be giving out tokens when some one sends ether. I have deployed it to Ropsten and I'm intended to deploy it to Main Net then, I'm intending to sell it to exchanges as well. So I'm looking for the steps to do that, following some tutorials I came to know that, I first have to get all my tokens from token contract to my wallet , How can I do that?

As in meta mask I can't see the tokens tab. The screen shot is attached.

[image: Meta Mask Account]

Can someone help me understand what is the way to get the tokens from contract to the wallet and then sell it to exchanges lets say: etherdelta.

P.S: I'm new to contract things and this is my first contract, so any help will be appreciated, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metamask UI in your screenshot seems to be, a bit different. Try reinstalling. It has several issues like that. Normally, there is a Token tab, under which 'ADD TOKEN' option resides.

[image]

On clicking ADD TOKEN button, the following box appears, where you can enter the contract address.

[image]

The token symbol and decimals of precision are automatically fetched. Once you added the token, the balance tokens in your account is displayed.[Correction: Metamask doesn't allow  to transfer tokens]. You can also modify your contract to send the token automatically, whenever someone send a specific amount of ether to this contract address.

> Can someone help me understand what is the way to get the tokens from contract to the wallet and then sell it to exchanges lets say: etherdelta.

From their git repo, you can see as,

> How to list a token:
>
> Any Ethereum-based token can be imported as a custom token and start trading on EtherDelta, without permission.
>
> To appear on the list of official tokens, the token owner/creator should PM Zack (EtherDeltaZack) with the following information:
>
> a. Token address (code should be verified on Etherscan)
>
> b. Official Web site (the token address should appear on the official Web site for verification)
>
> c. Paragraph description of the token.

Read more [here](https://github.com/etherdelta/etherdelta.github.io/issues/199)

Comment: I reinstalled the metamask and now it is running perfectly, I m able to import my tokens as well. Can you please share knowledge on how can I transfer it to some one ? as in contract, it is like getting ethers and giving out tokens. If account 0xa, holds 20 tokens and it want to send 10 of them to 0xb, how can I do that? will these tokens still be of some worth? and yes most importantly, the contract keeps a record of balances of tokens, it knows that 0xa holds 20 and then if 0xa send 10 of them through meta mask to 0xb, will contract still says that 0xa holds 20??

Comment: do u want to send using contract?

Comment: no meta mask. I know how to send through contract, I have implemented to get some ethers and it gives out tokens. But just to understand thing more clearly i wanna know that after someone imports its tokens to wallet, will he will be able to send it via metamask/my ether wallet or any other functionality other than contract to some one?

Comment: I'm absolutely sorry. I was wrong about the token transfer through metamask. It was my misunderstanding. Actually, metamask doesn't allow to transfer tokens. Answer edited now. Online wallets like myetherwallet, etherdelta etc. allow this.